# Python Datetime Problems Importing and Using Year, Month, Day Values

Tags: python, datetime

I'm importing values from a master file to be used within the datetime function.

I have a file called `data_inputs.py` which has the following:

```
start_year = 2003
start_month = 1
start_day = 1
```

in my `main_file.py` I have the following

```
from datetime import datetime
import data_inputs
datetime(data_inputs.start_year,data_inputs.start_month,data_inputs.start_day)
```

But I get the following error:

```
    TypeError: an integer is required
```

I tried this:

```
from datetime import datetime
import data_inputs

datetime(int(data_inputs.start_year),int(data_inputs.start_month),int(data_inputs.start_day))
```

But it still didn't work.

Insights?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I notice in your last code example that you've typed 'in' instead of 'int'. Could that be your issue?

Comment: You have a typo in `data_inputs_start_day`. It should be `data_inputs.start_day`. Fixing this in the first example should correct your code.

Comment: Have you thought about using timedelta? It allows you to manipulate time in the past and future more easily.

Comment: https://www.guru99.com/date-time-and-datetime-classes-in-python.html

Answer (score 0):

Logical explanation is that data_inputs.start_year, data_inputs.start_month and data_inputs.start_day are probably not integers, inspect their `type()` individually

Comment: Note that I attempt to force conversion using `int()`

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  data error in broader function that impacted this.  Thanks for all the assistance and sorry I wasted your time.